# Examples for commercial applications of data mining in pharmacy

Tags: machine-learning, references, data-mining

I've always heard that data mining and machine learning tools/techniques are heavily used in the pharmacy sector and biology, but I have never heard of companies that offer commercial applications of data mining for them. Once I heard my professor saying that if you really want to know the state-of-the-art in data mining, then look at the pharmacy sector. But again, I can't find any companies that apply them.

My questions:

1. Can you please tell me some commercial applications and usage of data mining in the pharmacy and biology sector?
2. What companies offer such applications for the pharmacy and biology sector?